# Highcharts Treemap doesn't work in production with Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, highcharts, production

I am currently creating a treemap in Highcharts and I have problems since it does not show me the results in production, but it does it in localhost. It also does not show me errors in the console, so I have no idea what is happening. The weird thing is if there is only one result, it shows it. If there are several results, it does not.

Any ideas? Has this happened to someone before?

Regards!

LOCALHOST:

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Dxt.png)

PRODUCTION:

[production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdt1x.png)

```
Highcharts.chart('heatmap', {
        colorAxis: {
            minColor: '#f5f5f5',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        series: [{
            type: 'treemap',
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            data: data_final_heatmap
        }],
        plotOptions: {
            treemap: {
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br>' +
                            '<b style="font-size: 20px;text-align: center;">' + ((this.point.value / sum_values) * 100).toFixed(1) + " %" + '</b> ' +
                            '<br/>';
                    },
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Porcentaje de estudiantes por institución <br>(Matriculas primer año)'
        }
    });
```

CONSOLE LOG PRINT:

[CONSOLE LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6yTN.png)

Comment: did you check your console. is there in error?

Comment: @ahmed Yes, there is no error :(

Comment: is all css files are in production, and check if they are local(on your server), and you are not using external css

Comment: Since the colorAxis show at the bottom I think there is a problem with `data_final_heatmap` on the production server. How do you load these data ?

Comment: In agree with @Core972, it looks like the problem with your data. Could you try to `console.log()` the `data_final_heatmap` variable, and send us the result?

Comment: @daniel_s I edited the post. that is the console log's print. :(

Comment: @JorgeMartinez, `value`should be a `number` not a `string` like in the image.

Comment: It's exactly what I just did a minute ago and it worked. Thanks a lot @Core972!